# Parse using Beautiful Soup

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup

This code works as far as using selenium to scrape data from tradingview and prints the results to the screen. Not sure how to pass this along to Beautiful Soup because it doesn't seem like I can print to a csv file using selenium?  Can anyone help.  Thanks so much.

Working Code

```
    from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

# will give a list of all close values
close_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class = 'tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--numeric']/span")


for index in range(len(tickers)):
   print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " " + close_values[index].text + " " )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.page_source` to get the HTML source of the webpage. To use it in BS you could do something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
#do whatever you want using soup object
```

Comment: Krushi, after I add that line of code you provided, do you know I could print to a CVS file.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer, please upvotes and Mark as answer so that others looking at this question could be helped.

Comment: Really wasn't too much help yet, but thanks for trying.